# Kendo UI for Angular: How to find out about changes in the Kendo-Grid?

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, dirty-checking

Is there any dirty flag in the Kendo-Grid? In the old JQuery version there was one, but in the Angular version I don't see anything like that: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/

And if no, how can I get to know about changes?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, [trackBy](https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction) is something you could use in that case.
I guess you could find the following link helpful
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-trackby

Please make a demo if you like to see if it works for you and check more things.

Answer (score 0):

The data items has a dirty field.

```
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var data = grid._data;
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            if(item.dirty)
            {
                // do something
                var foo = "kung";
            }
        });
```